# Best way to parse a table in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

I'd like to parse a simple table into a Ruby data structure. The table looks like this:

[alt text http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/446/picture5cls.png](http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/446/picture5cls.png) http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/446/picture5cls.png

**Edit:** [Here is the HTML](http://pastie.org/572069)

and I'd like to parse it into an array of hashes. E.g.,:

```
schedule[0]['NEW HAVEN'] == '4:12AM'
schedule[0]['Travel Time In Minutes'] == '95'
```

Any thoughts on how to do this? Perl has [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TableExtract/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm), which I think would do the job, but I can't find any similar library for Ruby.

Comment: Maybe post the actual HTML you want to parse?

Comment: The image and HTML links are now dead making the question less clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062051/how-do-i-parse-an-html-table-with-nokogiri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might like to try [Hpricot](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot) (`gem install hpricot`, prepend the usual `sudo` for *nix systems)

I placed your HTML into `input.html`, then ran this:

```
require 'hpricot'

doc = Hpricot.XML(open('input.html'))

table = doc/:table

(table/:tr).each do |row|
  (row/:td).each do |cell|
    puts cell.inner_html
  end
end
```

which, for the first row, gives me

```
<span class="black">12:17AM </span>
<span class="black">
    <a href="http://www.mta.info/mnr/html/planning/schedules/ref.htm"></a></span>
<span class="black">1:22AM  </span>
<span class="black">
    <a href="http://www.mta.info/mnr/html/planning/schedules/ref.htm"></a></span>
<span class="black">65</span>
<span class="black">TRANSFER AT STAMFORD (AR 1:01AM & LV 1:05AM)                                                                            </span>
<span class="black">

 N


</span>
```

So already we're down to the content of the `TD` tags. A little more work and you're about there.

(BTW, the HTML looks a little malformed: you have `<th>` tags in `<tbody>`, which seems a bit perverse: `<tbody>` is fairly pointless if it's just going to be another level within `<table>`. It makes much more sense if your `<tr><th>...</th></tr>` stuff is in a separate `<thead>` section [within the table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html). But it may not be "your" HTML, of course!)

Answer (score 2):

In case there isn't a library to do that for ruby, here's some code to get you started writing this yourself:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc=Nokogiri("<table><tr><th>la</th><th><b>lu</b></th></tr><tr><td>lala</td><td>lulu</td></tr><tr><td><b>lila</b></td><td>lolu</td></tr></table>")
header, *rest = (doc/"tr").map do |row|
  row.children.map do |c|
    c.text
  end
end
header.map! do |str| str.to_sym end
item_struct = Struct.new(*header)
table = rest.map do |row|
  item_struct.new(*row)
end
table[1].lu #=> "lolu"
```

This code is far from perfect, obviously, but it should get you started.