# How do I use XPath in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have not found any documentation nor tutorial for that. Does anything like that exist?

---

```
doc.xpath('//table/tbody[@id="threadbits_forum_251"]/tr')
```

The code above will get me any `table`, anywhere, that has a `tbody` child with the attribute `id` equal to "threadbits_forum_251". But why does it start with double `//`? Why there is `/tr` at the end? See "[Ruby Nokogiri Parsing HTML table II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062051/ruby-nokogiri-parsing-html-table-ii)" for more details.

---

Can anybody tell me how to extract `href`, `id`, `alt`, `src`, etc., using Nokogiri?

```
td[3]/div[1]/a/text()' <--- extracts text
```

How can I extract other things?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Seems you need to read a [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Your `//table/tbody[@id="threadbits_forum_251"]/tr` expression means:

- `//` - Anywhere in your XML document
- `table/tbody` - take a table element with a tbody child
- `[@id="threadbits_forum_251"]` - *where* id attribute are equals to "threadbits_forum_251"
- `tr` - and take its `tr` elements

So, basically, you need to know:

- attributes begins with `@`
- conditions go inside `[]` brackets

If I correcly understood that API, you can go with `doc.xpath("td[3]/div[1]/a")["href"]`, or `td[3]/div[1]/a/@href` if there is just one `<a>` element.

Comment: @Rubens thank you. And you're right I need to read the XPath Tutorial.I thought it was nokorigi doc I need to read... would you know if there is any tool that would give me full Xpath if I click and object on html page?

Comment: I dont know, but XPath isn't that hard; consider your filesystem, and lets assume every folder is a XML element; so, when you select your `system32` folder, you'll get `\windows\system32` path; just replace that `\\`` by `/`, consider attributes beginning with `@` and conditions by `[]` and you're good to go

Comment: I know this is an older answer but the link to the xpath tutorial is now broken.  I think it should now be http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: Fixed, @Axiombadger !

Answer (score 7):

Your XPath is correct and you seem to have answered your own question's first part (almost):

```
doc.xpath('//table/tbody[@id="threadbits_forum_251"]/tr')
```

"the code above will get me any <strike>table</strike> table's tr, **anywhere**, that has a tbody child with the attribute id equal to threadbits_forum_251"

---

`//` means the following element can appear anywhere in the document.

`/tr` at the end means, get the `tr` node of the matching element.

You dont need to extract each attribute one by one. Just get the entire node containing all four attributes in Nokogiri, and get the attributes using:

```
theNode['href']
theNode['src']
```

Where `theNode` is your Nokogiri [Node](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) object.

---

Edit:

Sorry I haven't used these libraries, but I think the XPath evaluation and parsing is being done by Mechanize. So here's how you would get the entire element and its attributes in one go.

```
doc.xpath("td[3]/div[1]/a").each do |anchor|
    puts anchor['href']
    puts anchor['src']
    ...
end
```

Comment: @Anurag thank you for nice explanation.I am using mechanize not pure nokogiri,can I use theNode['href'] somehow in [:title, 'td[3]/div[1]/a/text()'],? I want to extract href instead of text

Comment: `[:address, 'td[3]/div[1]/a/@href']` ?

Comment: i was searching for nokogiri tutorials and came across my own answer.. hehe :)

Comment: Mechanize uses Nokogiri internally, so it is using pure Nokogiri, it's just behind the curtain. Mechanize's [`Mechanize::Page.parser`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-parser) returns the root of the parsed page as a Nokogiri document.