# Ruby gem Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping, render, mechanize

Is it possible to use the render method of a controller to render the content of a Mechanize object? I tried:

```
def new
  a = Mechanize.new
  a.get('http://flickr.com/')

  render :html => a.current_page
end
```

which throws an error, as well as `render :text => a`, `a.page`, and `a.current_page`.

I understand that the `render` function is not expecting a Mechanize object, I just don't know what it wants and how to get it there.

I am at the beginning stages of my development and researching all web scraping frameworks for Ruby and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `body` method:

```
page = agent.get('http://www.example.net')
puts page.body[0..100]
=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml"
```

You can also dive deeper into the document using Nokogiri's capabilities. Mechanize is built around [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/), so you can get to the parsed document Nokogiri creates, then use CSS or XPath accessors to located sub-sections of the document. Once you've found what you want you can use the `to_html` method to have Nokogiri emit the HTML for the nodes or nodeset. See "[extract single string from html using ruby/mechanize (and nokogiri)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2114744/128421)" for information.

Now, while that'll work, you might want to consider whether you're violating the terms-of-service or copyrights by reusing the content directly on your page.